# need to convert a json response into java pojo where the response may return {} or [{},{}]

Tags: jackson, gson, json-deserialization, to-json, jsonresponse

Need to convert a json response to a java pojo in which a field(here in the examples 'performers' ) may either be returned as {} or [{},{}] or null as shown in the examples below:

example1:`performer value here is a list of datas '{}'.`

```
{

    title:"Sample title1",
    performers: {
         performer:[{
              creator: "AAAA",
              linker: "XXX",

         },
         {
              creator: "BBBBB",
              linker: "YYY",

         }]
     },

      venue_address: "sample addr1"

}
```

example 2:`performer value here is just data '{}'`

---

```
{


    title:"sample title2",
    performers: {
         performer: {
              creator: "AAAA",
              linker: "YYY",
         }
    },
    venue_address: "sample addr2"
}
```

---

example 3:`performer value is null here`

```
{

    title:"sample title3",
    performers:null,
    venue_address: "sample addr3"
}
```

How can we convert this json response to a java pojo with the help of `gson.fromJson` .As when trying to convert it into a pojo mentoning the performer field as list of perform field getting an error `"Expecting an OBJECT but found is ARRAY"`

Comment: Instead of 'null' it should be '[]'

Comment: Sridhar,the response for the same contains null value instead of [].

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is,

```
Whether or not you have performers or not it should be an array.
JsonArray should be enclosed with []. even you have ZERO or ONE or More perfomer
```

example 2:performer value here is just data '{}'

```
{
    title:"sample title2",
    performers: [{
        performer: {
          creator: "AAAA",
          linker: "YYY",
        }]
    },
    venue_address: "sample addr2"
}
```

example 3:performer value is null here

```
{
    title:"sample title3",
    performers:[],
    venue_address: "sample addr3"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sridhar for the reply.But the API response from the third party is in the format performers: {
         performer: {
              creator: "AAAA",
              linker: "YYY",
         }
    } .That is, the reponse body for the field performers in like {} not [{}].And if it has more than one performer then it comes as a list [{},{}],but in the case of a single perfomer which is in the format {} not [{},{}}.Please help me to solve the same.

Comment: @A.J.K:: Which Json Library you are using to parse. Is there any function to check if an JsonArray is NULL or NOT?

Comment: Also to check if it is JSON Array or Json Object using the library in build function?

Comment: ,it is the Gson library am using for the purpose :Gson().fromJson(<Response string>,<Class instance to convert to>).But i got the various format of the response by calling the same request manually through my web-browser.And thats how is came to know the various format of the response.

Comment: I also used Gson libary where you need to provide the semantics correctly otherwise it will throw error. You need change the API to respond correctly or you can do an work around like find and replace the NULL with [] but second one is really hard.

Comment: ,What does the semantics means .as you have mentioned we have to define the semantics correctly.Please try to figure out how the semantics for the mentioned format of the API response.

Comment: That is available in my answer itself. If you want more than one performer then you should enclosed it in [] which is the standard representation of json array. Even nothing is there then empty [] should be the value of Json Array.